# Rsync doesn't work in script

Tags: ssh, bash, rsync

I have 3 servers. On 1 server i have 2 scripts: 
1st script:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.2 'bash -s' < 2.sh
```

2nd script:

```
rsync -av --update /root/backup/* root@1.1.1.3:/root/backup/
```

I want to connect from 1st server with 1st script by ssh to 2nd server and perform copying data from 2nd server to 3rd server.
Connection from 1st server to 2nd server is OK, it asks for password for ssh. After that must be promt for a password for rsync, but i get errors. Rsync doesn't work. Errors:

> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far)
>   [sender]
>
> rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]

Firewalls on servers are disabled.
When i perform rsync on 2nd server without script, it works.

What is the problem?

---

debug

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "1.1.1.2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 1.1.1.2 [1.1.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 1.1..2:22 as 'wso2admin'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/wso2admin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 1.1.1.2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:k6J9Ez5V+PiqaBfUlN6LM7MwBGfPOrOTv4P/eyC3sGI
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/wso2admin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/wso2admin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 1.1.1.2
debug1: Host '1.1.1.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/wso2admin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55c2a242b850)
debug2: key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/wso2admin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
wso2admin@1.1.1.2's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 1.1.1.2 ([1.1.1.2]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug1: Sending command: bash -s
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 38
Permission denied, please try again.
debug2: channel 0: written 38 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 38
Permission denied, please try again.
debug2: channel 0: written 38 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 70
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
debug2: channel 0: written 70 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 73
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 70
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
debug2: channel 0: written 143 to efd 6
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2496, received 2836 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 18079.1, received 20541.8
debug1: Exit status 255
```

Comment: Do you login via SSH key when not using the script? Do you manually launch the script or is it executed from another daemon? What does `ssh -vvv` say when used in script?

Comment: Yes, i login via ssh without script. Yes, i manually launch the script

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the problem is the script or that rsync doesn't run from within but the ssh daemon configuration in the first server.

You may try edit in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

The error seems to be the password which makes me think either you're typing it manually (make sure it's the correct one) but at the same time make sure that you actually allow password logins.

Since you're also using root, you have to also make sure the following is present in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

You didn't specify distro, so most distros will have it in that path, otherwise you can check your specific or reply to the question and I'll do my best to answer.

I'd also recommend running from server a:

```
ssh-copy-id root@serverb
```

And the same on server b changing for server a.

That way your key will be present in origin and destination and ssh won't ask for a password.

Comment: Ur advices didn't help. I made ssh-copy-id root@serverb. There is no promt for password to connect to 2nd server, but there are still the same errors.

Comment: Did you replace serverb with the ip address or domain to the correct address? Are you able to ssh from both sides?

Comment: I found that there are more problems with ssh on 1st server. It can't connect to other servers. 2nd & 3rd servers can perform scripts when ssh doesn't ask for pwd, but servers can't perform script when ssh asks for pwd. I tried to do it on a new 4rd server, and on 4rd server everything works when ssh asks and doesnt ask for pwd. Some problems with ssh on 1,2,3 servers. I copied config from 4th server on other servers, it didn't help to other servers, so problem not in config. I tried to clean known_hosts, it didn't help too.

Comment: I will need you to post ssh root@server1,2,3 -vvv at least from one of the problem childs so we can get more information on this.

Comment: I found that 3rd server must contain authorized key for 2nd server. 1st & 2nd servers dont need to contain authorized keys. In this case script asks for pwd of 2nd server and then do rsync. Soon i ll publish debug log from ssh.

Comment: i added debug. Dont pay attention on string in debug: "debug1: Authenticating to 1.1..2:22 as 'wso2admin'". I changed IP address and missed 1 digit.